# MIPS Programming Homework - Updating Locations After Instructions

Tags: assembly, mips

For my Assembly Language course, I have been asked to fill out a table for the Assembly code in Figure 1 MIPS Assembly Code as shown in Figure 2.

[image: Figure 1]

In this code, my instructor is trying to implement a recursive function call to complete a factorial of a number. Using the parameters in Figure 2, I have filled out the following so far.

Parameters and my progress

[image: Figure 2]

I know the initial stack pointer starts at location 100, then decreased by 12 per the first instruction in the function continue. The frame pointer is updated to 112 at location 96, the return address would be updated at location 92, and n would be updated to 2 at location 88. This would be repeated until n reaches 1.

I am confused about a few things though. My first question would be regarding the return address. In the locations where the return address would be updated (92,80, and 68), would the return address be 5000 each time or would it be updated automatically to something else? I am confused about how exactly the return address will be updated since it isn't explicitly updated like the frame pointer is during each iteration of the loop.

My second question is regarding the next instruction following the line of code:

```
jal fact # recursive call to fact(n-1)
```

After this is done the following instruction is listed

```
lw $4, 0 ($29) # restore n
```

Would this happen at location 60? And then for

```
mult $2, $4 # fact (n-1) * n
```

would this happen at location 56?

My final question is restoring each of the registers. In the lines of code:

```
lw $4, 0 ($29) # restore n
lw $31, 4 ($29) # restore return address
lw $30, 8 ($29) # restore frame pointer
```

where exactly would the values of n, return address, and frame pointer be restored to? Would they be loaded onto their original values of 88,92, and 96 respectively?

This is my first experience with Assembly language and I appologize if something I said doesn't make sense or show proper research. I was not provided any similar examples from my instructor so this is what I found after doing some research.

Comment: Do you know how `jal`, `lw` and `sw` work? If no, you need to read their reference. If yes, just follow the instructions. It's unclear what "happen at location" should mean. An important note: We don't like questions with the code posted as a picture, nor multiple questions per post. Fix it. With a reference manual, a paper, a pencil and a rubber you should be able to do this :)

Comment: If the  "call" is done from address xyz, then return address is xyz+word_size ... always. No matter how deep you go into recursion. But the top-most level of recursive function is called from outside, so that one return address will be completely different. The inner return addresses will belong to inner calls (if it has multiple, if only single internal recursive call is done, then the return address will be same).

Comment: Also consider to use one of MIPS simulators like SPIM/MARS, where you can single-step over each instruction and watch after each step how did the registers and memory change. Comparing that to the reference guide describing particular instructions, it may get you on track faster then anything else (like asking on SO).

Comment: Now I see your pictures, that stack is filled reasonably ok, but return address  is `5000` only first time, the other times the `jal fact` will set `$31` to point to `lw $4, 0($29)` (the next instruction after `jal`. Actually I think on real MIPS it would be even one instruction later, as that `lw` would execute before jumping into `fact`, but judging how that code is written the delayed jumps are not considered for your course (I'm not MIPS programmer, so I may understand that part wrongly, maybe it doesn't apply to `jal` ... in SPIM/MARS it is switched off by default I think).